# Late to an Interview: Is a follow up email necessary?

Tags: interviewing

I was wondering if it is worth sending a follow up email after an interview I had even though I was late. But I would like to provide context to the situation if I may, to see if a follow up email is actually worthwhile.

I was about 3-4 minutes late to a 15 minute interview. I don't have a car, so a family member provided transportation but was late to the location.

When I came in I apologized and made a small excuse about it being "family issues" (excuses are a big no no!), we shook hands, and then the manager asked my name and then immediately stated that, "arriving late leaves a highly unfavorable impression". He than bluntly asked me, "Why should we consider you for our business if you are late to the interview?"

I mentioned to him my perfect attendance at my previous job last year, never missing a day, never calling out/sick and how I was almost always scheduled for opening shifts at my current and previous jobs.

One could say it was a very 'graceful' act for the manager to have the opening interview question give me a chance to **somewhat** redeem myself.

So with all things considered, should I provide the usual follow up email after the interview, perhaps adding an apology to the being late and mentioning again my reliability with previous jobs? Or should I not waste my time?

Comment: How was the interview other than u being late?

Comment: For sure I would not remind them you were late.

Comment: Smit, there were two people doing the interview. The district manager and the assistant manager. Both of them seemed very stoic during the process, so formal in fact it appeared artificial. The conversation seemed lopsided; halfway through the interview the district manager was mostly on his laptop and didn't seem to pay much particular attention to what I was saying. Looking at the computer more so than me, the interviewee. But the assistant manager however was actually giving me body language feedback and was actively listening to what I was saying. In short, not pleasant.

Comment: You should not consider a follow-up a waste of time, that is a fairly normal part of an interview exchange process, and any feeling of waste of time in your mind would likely come through to a reader.  I agree whole-heatedly with Paparazzi though, I would in no way remind them you were late.  No additional apologies, you already have and further bringing up the subject would hurt any damage control you did pull off.  That does not mean however you should not follow up with a thank you for your time note to re-iterate you still want to be considered, assuming that is the case.

Comment: @iLearnSlow Thats bad. But that could be that they are actually testing you? But nevertheless, if you have given your best, and read through below responses to get guage of what to put inside your email. You should be good to go. `Never beg for a job` - Remember this.

Comment: Fwiw, interviews are a two-way street. From what you've described -- a fairly blunt introduction, an interviewer tuning out the interview and working on his laptop instead, generally not pleasant -- it doesn't look like they've done a great job selling themselves as a place one would _want_ to work at. (Obviously, I don't know your situation and to what extent that can be a factor.)

Comment: While an interviewer looking at their laptop for a long portion of the interview might be a bad sign, it might not. Where I work, we are required to fill out a form for everyone we interview. I prefer to fill out the form during the interview, which means I spend 1/3 to 1/2 of every interview engrossed in my tablet, but actually listening to responses and making notes. We also continue to compare candidates for weeks on end, so sending a single follow up is a good idea and then move on to other opportunities. You may yet hear back from them.

Comment: Yeah, don't work there.  Send them a polite thanks for the interview, but don't say anything about wanting the job.  If they wish to move forward, politely decline.

Comment: I've had a fair few interviews where the two people will be like this - One won't talk, will take notes and generally seem 'uninterested' when infact they are making all the notes and possibly be a large part of the decision making process - the other person is generally the one who's better at spoken conversation, and asking the questions they need answering clearly.

Comment: Honestly, I would consider this (a manager making a big deal of me arriving 4 minutes late) a red flag. All other things being equal, I'd prefer to work for a company where people are polite about a one-time small lateness incident.

Comment: Is this really a case of wasting your time? The time you spent writing this question is about the same as the time to write your follow-up email. So just, send the email. Perhaps you're looking for absolution of your tardiness from strangers on the internet?

Comment: Not an answer, because it is too late for this, but the bulk of the response to the question about being late should have been an explanation of why you won't be late on the job. "Family issues" could be an on-going matter. "I had to get a ride today, but will do ... if hired" puts the lateness in the past, not the future.

Comment: Is this in the US? Thank-you emails are more common there than in other parts of the world so that could impact answers.

Comment: I agree with many of the comments - in the US, at least, I would consider that interview as several indications that it's NOT a positive place to work. Obviously, elsewhere, there may be cultural differences involved.

Comment: In my personal opinion, 3-4 minutes late for an interview is perfectly fine. If it would be 15 - 20 minutes or more, then yes, it's very bad first impression, unless you have a good excuse for it and/or call ahead to let them know. From the conversations I have with other interviewers, my view on it seems to be standard/common. This of course depends on the country.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> So with all things considered, should I provide the usual follow up
>   email after the interview, perhaps adding an apology to the being late
>   and mentioning again my reliability with previous jobs? Or should I
>   not waste my time?

A follow up note is always a good thing.

The emphasis of your follow-up note should be about thanking folks for the interview, on your fitness for the job, your enthusiasm about what you learned of the job and company, and your desire to move to the "next step" in the process.

At most, you should only incidentally apologize for being late. As you said "excuses are a big no no", so don't offer them again.

Comment: Why are excuses a big no-no in the hiring process?

Comment: @Christian Just accepting responsibility and moving on, _especially_ from minor incidents, is the way to go. If they noticed and you do this, they'll probably shrug it off, too. If they didn't notice and you do this, they'll hopefully think, "whatever." If you offer an excuse instead, regardless of what they _thought_ they'll now think, "really? come on, man, you were just a couple minutes late."

Comment: In the followup, I would mention briefly that the lateness was due to transportation issues (yes, this slightly contradicts what you said in the interview. You'll need to straighten that out) but that if hired you would be able to be reliably on time because your transportation plan is X.

Comment: "perhaps adding an apology to the being late and mentioning again my reliability with previous jobs?" I'd say that the mentioning of reliability is more of a "I screwed up and need to make amends" in a bad way. Just the apology should be sufficient. No need to seem desperate.

Answer (score 20):

**Do** follow up.

**Don't** mention your lateness.

My current position, I arrived 14 minutes late to the interview (I live about an hour away at the best of times, and I was delayed leaving home and got caught in rush hour). I got the job and have been here for nine years.

My being late certainly counted against me, but I overcame that in the interview and the technical evaluation after.

Comment: I very much like personal experiences in answers especially when there is a happy outcome. Cheers!!

Answer (score 8):

It would have been better to be 10 minutes early, for sure, however I think that most people would understand that sometimes there's simply circumstances outside of your control.

> **Clarification:** if there's a lot of competition for the position then being 5 minutes late can be a game breaker, however it's expensive to interview many candidates, so employers will typically only call in the people they're actually interested in hiring (on paper). In *that* situation being 5 minutes late is not a game breaker unless you also make other mistakes (might be used against you as a tie breaker between you and a similarly skilled candidate).

I would have kept the answer a little more general, however (family issues typically has negative undertones):

> I don't have experience travelling in this part of town, and ran into some heavy traffic. If I were travelling this route on a regular basis I would know to better account for such situations. My apologies.

Only *then* answer the follow up question, and talk about your perfect attendance at your other job, etc.

As far as sending a "Thank You" email, you most certainly should. Even if you don't get the job, it's not a "waste of your time", it's simply a standard courtesy which you should observe (unless the person flat out tells you not to let the door hit you on the way out or something).

Since you've already addressed being late (very directly) in your interview I wouldn't mention it in the email. If you feel *compelled* to do so, however, keep it brief:

> Dear X,
>
> Thank you for taking the time to see me today. I'm very excited at the prospect of bla bla bla. 
>  
>  I once again apologize for running late today, and hope my explanation as to why was satisfactory. 
>  
>  I look forward to hearing from you in the near future. 
>  
>  Regards,
>  iLearnSlow

Comment: "It would have been better to be 10 minutes early". Really depends on the company, 10 minutes early can be quite distracting, while 3-4 minutes late might not even be noticeable.

Comment: @Akavall I try to arrive at least 10 minutes early, but walk around the area until 5 minutes before the interview, at which point I enter and announce myself.  If the location is isolated, and not somewhere where I can inconspicuously wander, I'll wait in my car until 5 minutes before. Anything earlier can leave a negative impression.

Comment: Why is the first quote block formatted that way?

Comment: @lilienthal - because that's my style, and I intended the clarification to be an aside, as it were.

Comment: @AndreiROM Fair, but I'd recommend against it. Since you also use the formatting for example scripts in the same answer it makes it look odd and I first thought you had simply forgotten to attribute a source for an actual quote.

Comment: @Beofett, Yes. I think this is the best strategy.

Comment: I spent a while trying to find where you'd quoted your first blockquote from, eventually realising that it wasn't a quote after all having ⌘F'd parts of the quote. Blockquotes have a certain semantic meaning — aside isn't it. (cc @Lilienthal)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, **I would send a follow up email** just as you described in your answer, what do you have to lose?  I think you handled the situation very well.  Some people would crumble and just walk out of the interview.  Sending the follow up email message shows that your are *serious about the job*.

Going forward, I would plan on arriving at least **30 minutes early** to give your self a buffer, if your not doing something similar to that already.

Comment: Follow up e-mail for being late 4 minutes? Do they sell atomic clocks?

Comment: @Fernando The follow up email should not bring up the fact you are late, just the fact that you are appreciative of their time and are interested in the job.  What is wrong with an atomic clock anyway ;-) ?

Comment: @Fernando Also 4 minutes in a 15 minute interview means he missed over a quarter of it.

Comment: I don't know that turning up at the door 30 minutes early for an interview is all that good either: what would be best is get someone to drop you off at a coffee shop that is less than 5 minutes walk from the interview location and maybe read through some interview notes/prep - then leave the coffee shop 10 minutes before the interview and arrive at the door 5 minutes early.

Comment: I am serious - you don't say anything about what to do if you actually manage to arrive 30 minutes early - because the only other option is to walk in and be sat waiting for 30 minutes - I can tell you, almost no interviewer will start early (especially if they have a full day of interviews) - my way, you have the 30 minute buffer, you might get some last minute prep in, and you're guaranteed to arrive in a timely manner.

Comment: @HorusKol If you manage to arrive early, perhaps you can sit in your car and review your resume/potential answers in your head, find a cup of coffee, or whatever floats your boat.  Arriving plenty early is much safer that taking a chance on making a critical error by being late.

Comment: So, what's wrong with my advice?

Comment: @HorusKol What is the problem with arriving early? In the interview for my current job I arrived 15 minutes early and just waited in the waiting room's couch reading *"A dance with dragons"*. When I entered the interview room I just put the book on the table and my reading ended up being brought up in a good way in the conversation, as was the fact that the book was in english (not our native language, this was in Spain).

Comment: @xDaizu it depends - partly on how early you are (I'd say more than 15 minutes early), and on your behaviour when you arrive (believe it or not, I've had candidates who were confused as to why they had to wait after arriving early), and partly on the temperament of the interviewer (you, and other candidates, being early means you have to be "looked after"). Getting there very early may be an indicator that you aren't confident in your ability to plan to get somewhere on time, so pad your time - will you always aim to be 30 minutes early for work? Or end up being chronically late...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should send a follow up email. It doesn't really take that much effort (no more so than asking this question) and it can set you apart from other candidates.  Start by reiterating anything they did respond positively to, and concisely state why you are a great candidate.

Some have mentioned that you shouldn't remind them you were late. If the interviewer hadn't mentioned it, I would agree with this. However, given his reaction, I doubt he's forgotten about it. Giving an excuse about family issues was a terrible response, and he's likely wondering if those "issues" will cause problems in the future. Put this concern to rest by admitting you made a mistake by getting a ride from a family member, and how you will use a different, more reliable transportation option if they hire you. Reiterate how your usual method has never let you down in your current or past job, that you are always early, and your current supervisor will attest to that. If any of that isn't true, get as close to it as you can without lying. Take responsibility and demonstrate that it is a one-time mistake.

It would have been better if you had better addressed it in the interview or been early, but a quality thank you note may still save you if you aren't competing against a much better candidate.

Answer (score 1):

I will myself send an email regarding the points and discussion had during the interview (no matter if I am late, early or ...)

So do send an email, and do include your apology (not "sorry) and make sure that is not only be the topic of your email. Do write about the conversation that had happened. Also you may wish add in references that you had mentioned during the interview. This will bring their attention towards your work, and less on being "late"

Lastly, do not repeat. I mean don't just be sorry and make more mistakes. Apologize and move on.

These tips can help for your future interviews:

- Reach the location 30 mins early. Take any extra time to walk around and see the workplace, if possible network.
- Go through company related resources, such as their website.
- Read up on the job description for the position. If possible read other job descriptions too.
- Once the interview is over, do make sure to ask questions. Such as when will I know the results (or outcome).
- Send a follow-up email after a few hours so that it doesn't get mixed up with others.

Follow-Up Email:
- Thank the committee for their time.
- Thank them for pointing out any issues or problems with your skill sets (if any)
- Lastly send them any references, in the form of links, for them to learn more about you.
- Try not to write an email that is excessively long or too short.

Answer (score 0):

```
(excuses are a big no no!)
```

I somewhat disagree with this one, if you are late, you "must" provide a reasonable reason briefly. But I am not the master of behavioral psychology, so I am not aware if sharing the excuse makes you weak.

Regarding your question, the normal approach would be of course sending an email and not to apologize, however I found the interviewers approach highly unreasonable. Being late for 4 minutes is a minor issue, as we all have other duties, or living in large cities with traffic. I wouldn't even bother to inform about my attendance status as response.

And pushing the issue for the second time is unprofessional, in face the question itself probably belong to some HR interview-interrogation technique books.

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, [this LinkedIn post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/turning-away-late-candidate-james-murphy?published=t) seems to resonate a bit with you particular interviewer's opinion.  In essence, the author believes:

- Neither the interviewer or interviewee has an excuse to be late, since ways to communicate are plentiful
- Calling or sending some kind of notification *ahead* of time is preferred rather than after-the-fact

His concern comes from a candidate not showing the discipline to turn up on time to an interview, and how that may translate to their performance on the job.

> If you don't have the ability to show up on time for the chance to get the job, you do not have respect for mine or my management teams time and you DEFINITELY do not have respect for the opportunity!

I don't necessarily disagree with this opinion, and it also gives you anecdotal, real-world verification that being late *does* leave a negative impression on your opportunity.

On the flip side, I've had experience with a late interviewer; I declined any further work with them because they had disrespected my schedule not once, but twice.  (Why twice?  It's a long and complicated story, one which doesn't involve me necessarily looking for work at that time.)  Their tardiness and inability to really pencil me in at the specific agreed-upon time left me with an impression that that they wouldn't respect me when I walked in the doors, either.

To your question, here's what I'd recommend:

- **Treat this as a lesson learned.**  You're not going to get a chance to make this up, but in the future, keep in the back of your mind, if you *think* you're going to be late, then send ***any*** kind of message letting the person know you're going to be late.
- **Send a message, but *don't* emphasize the tardiness.**  You want to leave a lasting impression on the interview, and you don't want your lasting impression to be about how you were late.
- **In the face of adversity, overcome one shortcoming with a significant strength.**  Again, this is more of a lesson learned, but if you're interviewing for a position and there's something you definitely didn't do right, make it up in the interview by doing something ***extremely*** well.  The goal there is to overwrite a negative impression with a positive impression.  Yes, there may still be some concerns with tardiness, but at least you weren't thirty minutes late.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Yes.

Before elaborating on why I say yes, let's look at the other side of the coin, because there's quite a bit that can be learned from that first.  Here is why sending that E-Mail might not make sense:

You blew it.  You suspected that.  I'm going to just outright confirm that.

You could say that your ride blew it by being late, but you blew it by counting on that ride.  Maybe your cousin is typically responsible and relying on your cousin was a very sensible approach, but that doesn't change the fact that this job opportunity appears to have been blown.  That needs to just be accepted, simply on the grounds that it is reality.

Since you're asking "should I not waste my time", it sounds like you're not interested in spending time on something that is quite unlikely.  And I am saying, this seems quite unlikely.  That is the key basis for saying "no" for the question that was actually asked (even though, as my last paragraph a notes, I would actually personally recommend "yes").

Here are some of the reasons I see the chances as being so unlikely:

1. Being late is bad

   - No surprise here...  We all already knew that.
   - You did get unlucky.  Sometimes you can get lucky.  Maybe you show up, and the other person is also late.  Or maybe the interviewer doesn't ever learn that you are late for some other reason, like you show up and speak to a receptionist who doesn't report your lateness.  Unfortunately for you, you did not get such luck this time.
2. A made, and was made right away.  So we know this was noticed, and it did seem to matter.
3. Your response was bad; arguably terrible.

   - You said, “I mentioned to him my perfect attendance at my previous job last year, never missing a day, never calling out/sick and how I was almost always scheduled for opening shifts at my current and previous jobs.”
   - You claim that you are typically reliable enough to show up to work, sometime (on the right day).  You don't completely miss any days.  But you didn't say that you actually show up *on time*.  You didn't say that lateness is out of character for you.  Do you know what you did?  Just based on the text that you provided, it looks like you actually managed to sidestep the issue of punctuality, completely failing to directly address that issue that you were asked about.  So not only were you late, but you were evasive, and didn't fully demonstrate responsibility for an important issue.

     - A better approach (in my opinion) would have been something like “Something bad happened.  This lateness is out of my character.  I failed to be able to sufficiently compensate for the situation.”  At least that would have shown you : recognize the screw-up, are willing to acknowledge it, claim this is unusual, and will take the responsible approach of at least addressing problems as best as possible.  Unfortunately, that didn't happen, and there are situations where people who lack time-travel abilities just don't get second chances.  It does look like this is one of those situations.
4. Your comment (shown below the question) shows your fate is sealed.

   - “halfway through the interview the district manager was mostly on his laptop and didn't seem to pay much particular attention to what I was saying. Looking at the computer more so than me” -- Ooo-ouch!
   - “In short, not pleasant.” -- Ooo-ouch!
   - “But the assistant manager however was actually giving me body language feedback and was actively listening to what I was saying.”  Don't get much hope in this.  The Assistant Manager likely reports to the Manager (who may have been unavailable for this interview) who likely reports to the District Manager.  If the hiring decision is made by the District If Manager, it sounds like you're doomed.

     ***If*** the hiring decision is actually typically made by the Assistant Manager, you're likely still doomed, because the assistant manager is unlikely to want to rebel against the district manager.  If the district manager truly didn't like you, he may have allowed the interview to continue (in part just to avoid unnecessary conflict, and perhaps in part so the district manager could continue to further gauge the assistant manager), but chances are rather high that the district manager may have let the assistant manager know that the just-interviewed candidate was not a good match.  (Furthermore, the district manager may have told the assistant manager why.)

So, are you doomed?  Well, your chances of getting this job seem very, very slim, but there's good cause for hope.

It's time for me to explain why, despite all of the less cheery outlook I've provided so far, sending that follow up E-Mail is a good idea.

I've royally botched some interviews that I really needed in life.  I'm old enough that I didn't have this website available during that time of my life.  My life did have some challenges as a direct result of not handling interviews very well.  But eventually I learned some things and my skills increased and now there are plenty of people who would like to be in the shows that I am currently in.  So, life can get better.  (Not always quick nor easy, but it can happen.)  In my case, that required me learning, working, and continuing to try for positive things.  Took a while, but it did happen.

You, on the other hand, are using this website, which can be a great resource.  So you are doing a good, right thing.  Keep that up, by continuing to try to do the right and positive things (like spending the effort writing a brief E-Mail).

Typically the best answer is "Yes", sending that E-Mail is something worth doing, because the theory is that if there is still a 6% chance of success, that 6% is more than 2%, and sometimes things turn out unexpectedly well.  Since the cost to follow up is so inconsequential, then, yes, follow up.  (In other words, overall I agree with the first paragraph [Kat's answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/87076/45088) on why it is worthwhile.  I also agree with [Paparazzi's highly-rated comment](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/87063/late-to-an-interview-is-a-follow-up-email-necessary#comment-252579), because you basically want things to be as positive as possible, and it may be that your only conceivable chance involves further focus on positive things.  The third bullet point of [Makoto's answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/87198/45088), about a strength, provides you with the most promising strategy.)

Even if this apparent potential job opportunity was blown, just follow Kat's advice and try to forget about what would have been nice; instead focus on what is likely to be nice as you find and pursue another opportunity.

Answer (score -2):

TLDR: No, don't waste your time.

What I've learned is this:

- "If you're on time, you're late."
- "If you're early, you're on time."
- "If you're late, you're done."

Use this as a learning experience as the hiring manager already stated "why should we hire your if you're late?"

You already left a "sour" taste in their mouth about not being able to be on time to an interview, how are they supposed to trust you won't be late if you start working there?

I don't mean to come off condescending, but to put it bluntly, next time you need to plan accordingly, especially in your situation being that you don't have a car. You can't blame anyone but yourself in this situation as you didn't think about the person helping you being late.

I hope nothing but the best for you!

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question asked.

Comment: Yes it does. He asked "...Or should I not waste my time?" This is stating he shouldn't waste his time.  He should use it as a learning experience.

Comment: Fair enough, I can see how that answer could be implied. I think clearly stating "No, you should not waste your time" would improve this answer, though.

Comment: @jbh I can also see where you are coming from.  I'll use that for next time if a question similar to this arises. Thanks!

Comment: You can edit this answer to improve it; no need to wait for next time. Most answers get edited, so don't be shy about improving yours at any time. :)

Comment: While there are certainly employers who would take such a view; others are more rational and wouldn't pass up on the best candidate over a trivial amount of lateness.

Comment: Downvoted because I'm with Jack on this. The interviewer took an aggressive stance about the tardiness but that doesn't at all mean that the OP is out of the running for the job. His answer is what I would want to hear as an interviewer. Walking away is an overreaction here.

Comment: @Lilienthal I said don't send the email. That's what he asked.  I also stated things he should do in the future so that this doesn't happen again.

Comment: @Landon I don't disagree that you answered the question. I'm saying that I disagree with your answer, hence the downvote. If the OP followed this advice he'd give up a potential job offer for no real reason.

Answer (score -3):

Answer: no.

You've already talked about being late in the interview, you made it clear that it will not happen on a frequen basis and that you have a good record. So, unless the position is for a Nuclear power plant security enginner, there's no need for more excuses.

If you are good at what you do, and they don't hire you because of such small inconvenient, the better for you -  give some value to yourself.

I dont work at HR and don't live in the US, so I don't know what is best practice. IMO follow up emails are for special occasions, otherwise it shows you're insecure or desperate

Comment: What do you have to lose by sending a follow up email?  You would *not*  mention the fact you were late, of course.

Comment: @MisterPositive A lot. You're giving more excuses for something very small. If you solved a problem (OP did during interview), don't need to bring it again, it shows you're insecure.

Comment: Sending a follow up email along the lines of "Thank you for your time.  I am interested in the job" is standard practice.  I would not say "Thank you for the job, **sorry I was late**".

Comment: I totally agree with @MisterPositive . Sending a follow-up email after interview is regarded as a best practice, no matter of the situation such as late. Even if they reject me, I will send send a `thank you` email.

Comment: I dont work at HR and don't live in the US, so I don't know what is best practice. IMO follow up emails are for special occasions, otherwise it shows you're insecure or desperate.

Comment: @Fernando Well, the best practice in the US is to send a thank-you email and the OP mentioned that he'd normally send one.